# How to change the color of a bootstrap menu on wide screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been asked to change the color of  a bootstrap menu that was white into black and I have tried most things that I have found on the net but the menu does not change color on wide screen.

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kressly/79feLhek/14/)

Originally this is my code for the meny

```
<div class="col-md-7">

<div class="black_menu_top">

<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header bg_black">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>



        </div>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

                <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
          <a href="#ojm1" class="page-scroll" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">
            <i class='fa fa-home' style='color:initial'></i>  

           Home   


            </a>
        </li>


         <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
          <a href="#ojm2" class="page-scroll" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">
            <i class='fa fa-home' style='color:initial'></i>  

           WHO WE ARE 


            </a>
        </li>


        <li class="dropdown menu-withdraw ">
          <a href="#ojm3" class="page-scroll" rel="charger_tout" data-ajax="id_du_milieu" data-icon="Oui">
            <i class='fa fa-home' style='color:initial'></i>  

          WHAT WE DO 


            </a>
        </li>




          </ul>







        </div>

        <!--/.nav-collapse -->


      </div>
    </div>


</div>    

</div>
```

How can i change the white menu into a black menu with white text ? I have added some css file but it did not work

Comment: Are you simply trying to turn the entire NAV black with white text, nothing more?

Answer (score -1):

Place your site.css file AFTER bootstrap, and if that doesn't work put it before the bootstrap css file and put !important after the color codes that way it wont be overwritten, just make sure the class names match, or if you know the class name then search for it and find one that references #fff as the background-color and change it.. hope this helps

Comment: I'd like to ask the downvoters why they downvoted. Considering this works when I do it..

Comment: Thanks for the help though it could not solve my problem . I also don't know why people here downvote questions or answer without giving any explanation.

Comment: dang, maybe try using Dev tools to see what class it references??

Comment: @Krish ?? who's that too?

Comment: @Krish Thanks for the correction but see that there is still a background white on the menu on wide screen

Comment: i think that way you can sort it out @FerdineFaithfull